# rails variable within div class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just upgraded to Rails 4 (which may or may not be the issue.

In the past if I have wanted to use a variable within a div class name I have done something like the following.

```
<% my_class_name = "hello" %>
<div class = "#{my_class_name}">
..
</div>
```

(Obviously the variable would be set in the controller or be an instance of a collection)

However, when I do that now the output I see in the page source is exactly what has been wriiten i.e.

```
<div class = "#{my_class_name}">
and NOT
<div class = "hello">
```

Has something changed in rails 4 where this syntax is no longer valid? Or any other hints, greatly appreciated.

Interestingly when I use the following in a helper method, all is well...

```
content_tag(:div, class: "#{divclass}") do
```

Comment: Why you don't use <div class = <%= my_class_name %> ??

Comment: the part `<div class = "#{my_class_name}">` is actually HTML code, not Ruby code being evaluated on the server-side. Use @pabliiitoo solution to evaluate ruby code in your view

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use an erb tag in your erb templates:

```
<div class="<%= my_class_name %>">
```

Comment: Thanks to all on this. I had incorrectly tried class=<%= my_class_name%> but without the quotes on the outside which came up with some beautifully strange results, especially with multiple varibales!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enter the ERB/Ruby context using the `<%` tag.

```
<% my_class_name = "hello" %>
<div class="<%= my_class_name %>">
..
</div>
```

`#{}` is an interpolation inside an ERB/Ruby context.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, Max just beat you to the first correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% my_class_name = "hello" %>
<div class = <%= my_class_name %>>
..
</div
```

Use <%= %> instead of #{}

Comment: Thanks fr the respnse, although you need the quotes around the <% tag